# puppeteer page.evaluate loop wait between click

Tags: javascript, loops, puppeteer, evaluate

I'm trying to make 1 sec wait between clic inside my loop, it not working, have you an idea how can i make that ?
Thanks

```
await page.goto("https://mywebsite.local");
page.evaluate(()=>{
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("a.special.video");//25-30 element
    for (let element of elements){
        setTimeout(() => {
            element.click();
        }, 1000);  
    }
});
```

i must wait between click because on every click i'm waiting ajax refresh content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the index value to get the 1 second separation before the clicks:

```
page.evaluate(()=>{
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("a.special.video");//25-30 element
    elements.forEach((element, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            element.click();
        }, index * 1000);  
    })
});
```

Comment: Nice to hear! :) You can click the tick to choose it as the correct answer